# How to track a domain name of a client into ma server,when a user clicked on a client page

Tags: php, html, iframe

In the client application a ”click here” button is clicked, an Iframe is activated and navigated to particular URL which I already specified in that Iframe.  Next step a window is popped, simultaneously my server page is getting loaded into it.  Here I should get the Domain Name of the client from where the “click here” button is activated.

Is there any method to get the client Domain Name into my server which is getting loaded.  I can’t include any PHP functions in client page because it's pure HTML.

Just below I am giving the link  which is available in client page :

http://example.biz/manu/index.php

Comment: `can’t include any PHP` retag?

Comment: What do you mean by "domain name"? Do you want to know the URL of the page on which your site is included in an iframe?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get the parent URL from an Iframe's content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115526/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-parent-url-from-an-iframes-content)

Comment: domain name means client website name;

Answer (score 0):

try this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="foo"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#foo").append(
    '<iframe src="'+location.hostname+'/manu/index.php"></iframe>'
);
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/JellyBelly/FZNEA/)

Comment: actually i need to get the client domain name; aftr a button click ma server page loaded into client home page in an iframe. a button,  iframe link and one js file oly m just supposed to giv to client page.I cannot mention any js function to get domain name and cant pass with url.

Comment: we cannot include any php tag bze this code may be workin in html site(client)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a js function to get the domain name and append that variable with Url which is mentioned in that iframe.