# document.referrer isn't providing the original page url?

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

My script is running in an iframe in an iframe and I'm trying to get the root referrer (the url the iframe is on). It's not working. Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var referrer_url = document.referrer;
    document.write("You come from this url: " +referrer_url);
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [access parent url from iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420004/access-parent-url-from-iframe) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115526/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-parent-url-from-an-iframes-content or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724969/get-the-parent-url-of-iframe-in-php or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413414/get-parent-location-url-iframe-from-child-to-parent

Comment: What do you mean by, "It's not working?"  Do you get the wrong answer? Is it null?  An error? vvv whoa good one :-)

Comment: @Esailija It's the current economic climate. It's tough out there...

Answer (score 2):

Document.referrer doesn't get set on all occasions.

You should use `window.top.location.href.toString();` but it requires that they both are on the same domain.